# How to access a visual component from another form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox in my main form.

Now I have created a function which is used to set the value of the text box.

```
public void SetTextOfTextBox(String text)
{
  textbox1.text = text;
}
```

Now in my main form I call another class (class b) which does some work for me. Now i want to be able to call my setTextofTextBox function from class b.

Now if I try `Form1.SetTextOfTextBox("test");` this doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

How do I access components of a a Form from another class.

Comment: Did you create Form instance before you try to access it? Is Form1 variable or Form name?

Comment: Well the form is the class which is running. So it calls class b. surely it is already instantiated?

Answer (score 2):

> Form1.SetTextOfTextBox("test"); this doesn't work

This doesn't work because SetTextOfTextBox is not static and you cannot access a non-static function directly. And you can't make it static either because your textbox is form level control.

> How do I access components of a a Form from another class

You will have to pass the instance of Form1 to your other class to access it. Something like

```
  Class B = new ClassB(this);  //where this is the instance of Form1.
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a reference to the instance of Form1 in class b, otherwise you cannot call member methods.

Something like this:

```
class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form {
    void functionInForm1() {
        ClassB objB = new ClassB();
        objB.doSomething(this);
    }
}

class ClassB {
    void doSomething(Form1 form) {
        form.SetTextOfTextBox("test");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Find out* the `Form1` and call the method:

```
  foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms) {
    Form1 myForm = form as Form1;

    if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, myForm)) {
      myForm.SetTextOfTextBox("Test");

      break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try using delegates.

Specify the delegates in your ClassB like this.

```
public delegate void OnDone(string textValue);
public event OnDone OnUserDone;
```

after completing the task in ClassB call event:

```
OnUserDone("DoneClassB");
```

When u create the object of class in form map delegate function.

```
 Classb b=new Classb();
 b.OnUserDone += new Classb.OnUsrControlDone(CompletedClasss);
```

Define the function in form like below.

```
void CompletedClasss(string textValue)
{
            SetTextOfTextBox( textValue);
}
```