# getting component info from another class fails in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform with button and opendialog, here is my code :

[Form1.cs]:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Class1 obj=new Class1();
                obj.get_info(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

[class1.cs]:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
    {
        class Class1
        {

            private IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents(Form frm)
            {
                return from field in GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                       where typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
                       let component = (Component)field.GetValue(frm)
                       where component != null
                       select component;
            }

            public void get_info(Form frm)
            {
                foreach (Component c in EnumerateComponents(frm))
                {
                    if (c.GetType() == typeof(OpenFileDialog))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Detected OpenFileDialog");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

why it does not work ?

I have visited these links below but I could not utilize them to solve my problem :

[Access form component from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803970/access-form-component-from-another-class)
[Accessing Form's Controls from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983427/accessing-forms-controls-from-another-class)
[How to access a visual component from another form in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131068/how-to-access-a-visual-component-from-another-form-in-c-sharp)

thanks

Comment: Break up the LINQ block into separate statements that assign their results to a variable, and inspect those variables.

Comment: @CodeCaster : can you please provide example or post your answer. I am a super newbie :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?  Bad return value?  Exception thrown?  App crashes?

Comment: @DonBoitnott : it does not show messagebox

Comment: First off, it looks like you're trying to spot an open instance of an `OpenFileDialog`, but you never produce one, so how would the test ever pass in that example code?

Comment: @DonBoitnott :i want to detect the existence of an openfiledialog component in the main form and i have dragged an openfiledialog in the component part of the form. the above code works fine in the main form1 class but if i do the same in another class like class1 , it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking the wrong type to provide your answer.  Instead, ask for the `frm.GetType()`:

```
private IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents(Form frm)
{
    return from field in frm.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        where typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
        let component = (Component)field.GetValue(frm)
        where component != null
        select component;
}
```

It worked in the `Form` code because inherently, `GetType()` is equivalent to `this.GetType()`, with *this* being the form.